# Native drag and drop target is not droppable (but its children are)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement row reordering using HTML5 native drag and drop: simply drag to re-order the rows. Sources are also targets, and when dropped, the source moves in front of the target.

This example partially works, but the problem is that the drop only succeeds when dropping into one of the child input-type elements of the intended drop target. Why are drops only succeeding for these child elements, instead of their parent row div?

```js
function handle_dragleave(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.currentTarget.setAttribute('style', "border-top:none;");
}

function handle_dragstart(ev) {
  console.log("drag: " + ev.currentTarget.id);
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = "dashed";
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.currentTarget.id);
}

function handle_drop(ev) {
  console.log("drop: " + ev.currentTarget.id);
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
  var sourceId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var source = document.getElementById(sourceId);
  ev.currentTarget.before(source);
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
  ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
}

function handle_dragover(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.currentTarget.setAttribute('style', "border-top:solid;");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="r1" class="row" style="cursor:move" draggable="true" 
    ondragleave="handle_dragleave(event)" ondragstart="handle_dragstart(event)" 
    ondrop="handle_drop(event, this)" ondragover="handle_dragover(event)">
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <textarea class="form-control">First</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12"><hr/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="r2" class="row" style="cursor:move" draggable="true" 
    ondragleave="handle_dragleave(event)" ondragstart="handle_dragstart(event)" 
    ondrop="handle_drop(event, this)" ondragover="handle_dragover(event)">
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <textarea class="form-control">Second</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12"><hr/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an element to be droppable, it's necessary to prevent default action in the `dragover` event:

```
function handle_dragover(ev)
{ 
  ev.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.    
  ev.currentTarget.setAttribute('style', "border-top:solid;");   
}
```

`stopPropagation();` also appears to be unnecessary for this to work properly.